# Generate square wave in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, wave

I have inefficient code of a square wave. I have 2 buttons, 1 table and something like a coordinate system where the square appears in. I want the wave to scroll/move in real time until it hits the end of the coordinate system instead of just appearing by selecting both of the buttons. Additionally, if anyone has a better way of drawing a square wave please tell me.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawLine(20, 300, 20, 450);
    g2d.drawLine(20, 350, 400, 350);
    g2d.drawLine(20, 400, 400, 400);
    g2d.drawLine(20, 450, 400, 450);

    if (this.jButtonSTART.isSelected() & this.jButtonAND.isSelected()) {
            this.draw(g2d);
        }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d) {
    boolean up = true;
    while (x <= 380) {
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        if (x > 0 && x % 95 == 0) {
            up = !up;
            g2d.drawLine(20 + x, up ? 315 : 350 + y, 20 + x, up ? 350 : 315 + y);
        } else {
            if (up) {
                g2d.drawLine(20 + x, 315 + y, 21 + x, y + 315);
            } else {
                g2d.drawLine(20 + x, 350 + y, 21 + x, y + 350);
            }
        }
        x++;
    }
    x = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to draw your square wave and move it:

1. Create a BufferedImage that is longer than your GUI. It should have length that matches a the period of your square wave and be at least twice as long as the GUI component that it's displayed in.
2. Draw within the paintComponent method override of a JPanel, not the paint method.
3. Call the super's paintComponent method first within your override.
4. You'll draw the image using `g.drawImage(myImage, imageX, imageY, this)` where imageX and imageY are private instance fields of the JPanel-extending drawing class.
5. In a Swing Timer, advance imageX with each tick of the Timer, that is each time its ActionListener's actionPerformed method is called).
6. Then call `repaint()` on the drawing JPanel within the same actionPerformed method.
7. Done.

for example, note that this code does not do exactly what you're trying to do, but does show an example of Swing animation using a Swing Timer and paintComponent.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MoveWave extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = 200;
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 40;
    public static final int DELTA_X = 2;
    public static final int STARTING_MY_IMAGE_X = -PREF_W;
    private static final Color COLOR_1 = Color.RED;
    private static final Color COLOR_2 = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private static final int CIRCLE_COUNT = 10;
    private BufferedImage myImage = null;
    private int myImageX = STARTING_MY_IMAGE_X;
    private int myImageY = 0;

    public MoveWave() {
        setBackground(BG);
        myImage = new BufferedImage(2 * PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = myImage.createGraphics();
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(new GradientPaint(0, 0, COLOR_1, 20, 20, COLOR_2, true));
        for (int i = 0; i < CIRCLE_COUNT; i++) {
            int x = (i * 2 * PREF_W) / CIRCLE_COUNT;
            int y = PREF_H / 4;
            int width = (2 * PREF_W) / CIRCLE_COUNT;
            int height = PREF_H / 2;
            g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
        }
        g2.dispose();
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (myImage != null) {
            g.drawImage(myImage, myImageX, myImageY, this);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            myImageX += DELTA_X;
            if (myImageX >= 0) {
                myImageX = STARTING_MY_IMAGE_X;                        
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MoveWave");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new MoveWave());
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your timer's actionPerformed method should reset the imageX value whenever it  reaches a full wavelength. and you should also add a ComponentListener whose componentResized() method re-creates the image for the new size of the component.

Comment: @FredK: true, or for my example program (see above), I simply fix the size of the GUI.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels Thanks a lot for the help! I'm really just a beginner so I'm having a hard time understanding your steps. You lost me after the 2nd step. Could you be a bit more elaborate? I'm assuming you wanted me to create paintComponent method, because I didn

Comment: @Nest: Read the tutorial on Swing graphics as a first step: * [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)